# Merge "ifort" and "intel-visual-fortran"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Why are there OS dependent tags for Intel's Fortran compiler? I know, Intel is calling their tool [ifort](/questions/tagged/ifort) for GNU Linux and [intel-visual-fortran](/questions/tagged/intel-visual-fortran) for Windows - but isn't it essentially the same thing?

Wouldn't it therefore be better to use one of those tags and symlink to the other?

Comment: The two tag wikis say two different things.  ifort is apparently good for all operating systems, whereas Visual Fortran is intended only for Windows.